# Change vertical spacing between blocks in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

The title says it all. How how can I change the vertical grid spacing between two blocks in a tikzposter document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the default vertical spacing between blocks, use the class option `blockverticalspace=<length>`. To adjust the position of a single block, you can perhaps set `bodyoffsety` and `titleoffsety` in the `\block` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  a2paper,
  blockverticalspace=5cm
  ]{tikzposter}
\begin{document}
\block{Abc}{Def}
\block{Foo}{Bar}
\block[
  bodyoffsety=3cm,
  titleoffsety=3cm
]{Bar}{Baz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. A feature of `tikzposter` (as far as I can tell) is that a block is positioned immediately below the previous block, even if there's another block defined further up that is longer, with the result that blocks can overlap. `\block[bodyoffsety=-5cm,titleoffsety=-5cm]` with negative adjustment saved my day.